# Loop used to execute a procedure multiple times fails during nth run

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, stored-procedures, cursor

I have the following code running a loop

```
DECLARE @table_name NVARCHAR(100)
, @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
, @sp_name NVARCHAR(100)
, @rep_dt nvarchar(10)
, @min_rep_dt DATE

DECLARE mycursor CURSOR
LOCAL STATIC
LOCAL READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR
SELECT 
table_name
,sp_name
,report_dt
FROM staging.raw_sp_runlist

OPEN mycursor
FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor
INTO @table_name, @sp_name, @rep_dt

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = N'EXEC '
            + @sp_name
            + ' @ds_table_name = ' + '''' + @table_name + ''''
            + ' ,@report_dt = ' + '''' + @rep_dt + ''''

    EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql

    FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor
    INTO @table_name, @sp_name, @rep_dt

END
```

CLOSE mycursor
DEALLOCATE mycursor

Example of table being used to set the sp and parameters

| table_name | SP_Name | report_dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| raw_table_A | run_raw_table | 20230101 |
| raw_table_B | run_raw_table | 20230201 |

The reason this is not a union is because we want to handle running a single months or multiple months between a start and an end date. The first table will be appended but the rest of the database will be ran as delta loads on a monthly basis.

What happens is the loop runs through the stored procs for about 15 runs and then the stored proc doesn't complete.

When I run the stored proc that will be executed in the loop outside of the loop it runs no issues, I have also tried different stored procs in the loop and it always fails on the 15th run?

Comment: Add a tag for the dbms used. The above code is product specific.

Comment: Well, how do we know what the issue is? Check the running processes (for example in activity monitor or sp_whoisActive), there's probably something blocking your run.

Comment: And is this running in a transaction?

Comment: Also, why aren't you fetching all the columns right away in the cursor? you know that cursor can fetch more than one variable at a time?

Comment: I would also suggest running a local static read_only forward_only cursor to avoid potential locking / overhead

Comment: Thank you @siggemannen i have made the edit to the code, please see post edit.
I have had a dba check and there is nothing blocking when this is being executed.

Comment: You don't need dynamic SQL for this. Just put the procedure name in a variable and do `EXEC @sp_name @ds_table_name = @table_name, @report_dt = @rep_dt;`

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler version of your code would look something like this..

```
DECLARE @table_name NVARCHAR(100)
    ,   @sp_name NVARCHAR(100)
    ,   @rep_dt DATE
    ,   @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE mycursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT table_name , sp_name , report_dt FROM staging.raw_sp_runlist

OPEN mycursor FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor INTO @table_name , @sp_name , @rep_dt

    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN

        SET @Sql = N'Exec ' + QUOTENAME(@sp_name) 
                 + N'   @ds_table_name = @table_name '
                 + N' , @report_dt = @rep_dt '

        EXEC sp_executesql @Sql
                        , N'@table_name NVARCHAR(100) , @rep_dt DATE'
                        , @table_name
                        , @rep_dt

        FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor INTO @table_name , @sp_name , @rep_dt

    END

CLOSE mycursor 
DEALLOCATE mycursor
```

Also I would suggest to create a separate proc to execute procs and add error handling so if a proc execution fails this process continues to execute next proc and also log some error details.

I implemented a similar solution at my place but it has a much more sophisticated implementation and a lot of error handling and reporting on top of this process.

Comment: Thanks, I posted the edit just before you commented, appreciate the code example :)

Answer (score -1):

Fixed with the below code:

```
DECLARE @table_name NVARCHAR(100)
, @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
, @sp_name NVARCHAR(100)
, @rep_dt nvarchar(10)
, @min_rep_dt DATE

DECLARE mycursor CURSOR
LOCAL STATIC
LOCAL READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR
SELECT 
table_name
,sp_name
,report_dt
FROM staging.raw_sp_runlist

OPEN mycursor
FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor
INTO @table_name, @sp_name, @rep_dt

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN TRY

    SET @sql = N'EXEC '
            + @sp_name
            + ' @ds_table_name = ' + '''' + @table_name + ''''
            + ' ,@report_dt = ' + '''' + @rep_dt + ''''




    EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH

    FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor
    INTO @table_name, @sp_name, @rep_dt

END

CLOSE mycursor
DEALLOCATE mycursor
```

Comment: For diagnosis, are you actually catching an error and if so ... what? Is there a way you could address the root cause rather than just swallowing it in a catch block.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**